# mySql advice needed for query in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have two models, listings and bookings. listings hasmany bookings. I'm trying to write a query to return all listings who DON'T have bookings booked during a certain time period.

I've gotten so far but I'm still a newbie to cakephp and my sql isn't great either. In my controller method I have

```
$conditions = array(
                            "OR" => array(
                                "Listing.address_one LIKE" => "%".$area."%",
                                "Listing.address_two LIKE" => "%".$area."%",
                                "Listing.city LIKE" => "%".$area."%",
                                "Listing.postcode LIKE" => "%".$area."%",
                                "Listing.title LIKE" => "%".$area."%",
                            )

                        );


    $this->paginate = array(
                'conditions'=> $conditions,
                'joins'=>array(
                          array(
                           'table'=>'bookings',
                           'alias'=>'Booking',
                           'type' =>'inner',
                           'conditions' =>array('Booking.listing_id = Listing.id', 'Booking.checkin NOT BETWEEN ? AND ?' => array($to, $from))
                          )
                        ),
                'limit' => 10,
                );

    $data = $this->paginate();
```

That just gets all the listings which actually have bookings associated with them. Not only that but it doesn't ignore any bookings which are booked for the given period.

The SQL it creates is:

```
SELECT 
    ...
FROM 
    `database`.`listings` AS `Listing` 
INNER JOIN 
    `database`.`bookings` AS `Booking` ON (
        `Booking`.`listing_id` = `Listing`.`id` AND
        `Booking`.`checkin` NOT BETWEEN '18-07-2013' AND '10-07-2013'
     ) 
LEFT JOIN 
    `database`.`users` AS `User` ON (
        `Listing`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`
     ) 
WHERE (
    (`Listing`.`address_one` LIKE '%belfast%') OR 
    (`Listing`.`address_two` LIKE '%belfast%') OR 
    (`Listing`.`city` LIKE '%belfast%') OR 
    (`Listing`.`postcode` LIKE '%belfast%') OR 
    (`Listing`.`title` LIKE '%belfast%')
)
LIMIT 10
```

Which looks kinda rightish(?) but obviously isn't. Anyone any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> return all listings who DON'T have bookings booked during a certain time period

The first step in generating an appropriate find, is to understand the sort of query that is required - i.e. start at the database.

The query in the question is looking for all listings (matching conditions) with a booking that is outside the range of dates. I.e. a booking for belfast at any time except `BETWEEN '18-07-2013' AND '10-07-2013'`. That is not the same logic as the sentence above.

There are multiple ways to achieve that, here are two in order of ease of implementation:

### Use a left join

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    `nights2stay`.`listings` AS `Listing` 
LEFT JOIN                                                             # <-
    `nights2stay`.`bookings` AS `Booking` ON (
        `Booking`.`listing_id` = `Listing`.`id` AND
        `Booking`.`checkin` BETWEEN '18-07-2013' AND '10-07-2013'     # <-
     ) 
LEFT JOIN 
    `nights2stay`.`users` AS `User` ON (
        `Listing`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`
     ) 
WHERE 
    (
        (`Listing`.`address_one` LIKE '%belfast%') OR 
        (`Listing`.`address_two` LIKE '%belfast%') OR 
        (`Listing`.`city` LIKE '%belfast%') OR 
        (`Listing`.`postcode` LIKE '%belfast%') OR 
        (`Listing`.`title` LIKE '%belfast%')
    ) AND
    `Booking`.`id` IS NULL                                            # <-
LIMIT 10
```

I.e. join bookings with dates matching the date range, and only return records where there *is not* a booking.

To achieve the above query is very easy:

```
function index() {
    ... # Existing code

    $this->paginate['joins'][0]['type'] = 'LEFT';
    $this->paginate['conditions']['Booking.id'] = null;
    $data = $this->paginate();

    $this->set('data', $data);
}
```

### Use NOT EXISTS

Alternatively, use [NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    `nights2stay`.`listings` AS `Listing`
                                                                      # <
LEFT JOIN 
    `nights2stay`.`users` AS `User` ON (
        `Listing`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`
     ) 
WHERE 
    (
        (`Listing`.`address_one` LIKE '%belfast%') OR 
        (`Listing`.`address_two` LIKE '%belfast%') OR 
        (`Listing`.`city` LIKE '%belfast%') OR 
        (`Listing`.`postcode` LIKE '%belfast%') OR 
        (`Listing`.`title` LIKE '%belfast%')
    ) AND
    NOT EXISTS (                                                      # <
        SELECT                                                        # <
            *                                                         # <
        FROM                                                          # <
            `nights2stay`.`bookings` AS `Booking`                     # <
        WHERE                                                         # <
            `Booking`.`listing_id` = `Listing`.`id` AND               # <
            `Booking`.`checkin` BETWEEN '18-07-2013' AND '10-07-2013' # <
    )                                                                 # <
LIMIT 10
```

This kind of query is more logical, and has the benefit that it is a meaningful query "find me these where there are no (...)". It will *probably* perform better, though as with any query it's best to profile/explain queries before choosing one or the other.

To achieve the above query [is a little more involved in CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries) but it's not difficult:

```
function index() {
    ... 

    $db = $this->Listing->getDatasource();
    $subQuery = $db->buildStatement(array(
        'fields'     => "*",
        'table'      => $db->fullTableName('bookings'),
        'alias'      => 'Booking'
        'conditions' => array(
            '`Booking`.`listing_id` = `Listing`.`id`',
            "`Booking`.`checkin` BETWEEN '$to' AND '$from'"
        )
    ));

    $expression = $db->expression('NOT EXISTS (' . $subQuery . ')');

    $this->paginate['conditions'][] = $expression;
    $data = $this->paginate();

    $this->set('data', $data);
}
```

Comment: Hi @AD7six , thanks for the help. I really really appreciate it. So  tried out the first option just using $this->Listing->query() and it didn't seem to work as hoped so I've been trying to get the 2nd option to work. Which does look a better way. I've been reading up on subqueries but can't figure out why this isn't working. I'm getting a couple of errors. One was it was missing the model as the 2nd argument. I put 'Booking' in there and it solved that. But I'm still getting Indirect modification of overloaded property ListingsController::$paginate has no effect

Comment: The above is due to the line: $this->paginate['conditions'][] = $expression; I'm also getting the error: Implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed [CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php, line 1720] but perhaps that will dissappear if the other error gets sorted.

Comment: `One was it was missing the model as the 2nd argument.` I don't know what that refers to. `I'm still getting Indirect modification of overloaded property ListingsController::$paginate` - still? The syntax in the answer is for brevity - i.e. just make sure your paginate settings match. You cannot modify $this->paginate (the property) after calling $this->paginate(); (the function) - You don't mention you're using 2.3 ;)

Comment: Hi AD7six, thanks again for the help. I've been fiddling about with the pagination property but I can't figure out what goes where. To be honest I'm getting a bit panicked and frustrated because I'm under a bit of pressure to get this working. I think I've bitten off a bit more than I was ready to chew. Any chance I could make a donation to you/charity of your choosing, email you the file and get you to sort it? :)

Comment: What do you reckon? :) I could paypal you some money and you could buy some nice wine and food. Or the next time someone asks you to sponsor them or donate to something, I could do it for you.

Comment: If you need interactive help I recommend asking on [the irc channel](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/cakephp-overview/where-to-get-help.html#the-irc-channel)